# Retrofit 2: how to get multiple values from Response body

Tags: android, kotlin, flask, retrofit2

how to get mutli values from flask return to retrofit
for example i get lattitude & longitude from flask but msg show 1 value only
flask:

```
@app.route('/api/xyz', methods=['POST'])
def xyz():
return str(latitude), str(longitude)
```

android: Retrofit2

```
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val msg = response.body()?.string()


           }
   }
```

msg only get 1 value how to get multiple values.

Comment: Did you try wrapping latitude and longitude in one object?

Comment: i send the latitude  & longitude from flask to android using retrofit2